# Can you get a list of all Google Workspaces with Domain-Wide Delegation for a certain service account?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-iam

So we have a Google service account for the company used to import certain data for our customer using Google Workspace. The thing is that the companies need to follow our guide to set up some stuff, including the domain-wide delegation on their Workspaces.

I'm wondering if their is a way to see a list of client who successfully gave our service account permission on their workspace with a list of scopes so that I can better troubleshoot the errors when the imports don't work. Most of the time it is because their domain-wide delegation is not set up so this would save me a lot of time and give me certitude combined with the error messages received from the Google API.

After lots of research I can't seem to find anyone with the same needs so maybe there is a better way to get such knowledge?

Comment: I am not aware of an API that returns DWD information. I would simply create various configuration failures and document the error messages. Then you will know what they configured correctly and incorrectly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.